# jHipster Swagger UI path issues when deployed to Cloud Foundry

Tags: jhipster, swagger-ui, cloud-foundry, jhipster-registry

I have deployed Registry, Gateway and a microservice to Cloud Foundry. The microservice is available in registry and has also registered successfully in Gateway.

When trying to invoke calls in Swagger UI, the Swagger-generated url goes thus:

```
https://<microservice_route_with_port>/api/service_name/api/action_name
```

The above  fails with "*No response from server*" error.

When invoking through Swagger UI, the URL that I am expecting - and which is validated to be work fine through Curl call - is:

```
https://<gateway_route_without_port>/service_name/api/action_name
```

BTW, direct service call through CURL or POSTMAN works fine too (by-passing the Gateway):

```
https://<service_route_without_port>/api/action_name
```

The application.yml file has the below configuration:

```
eureka:
instance:
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]}
```

1. How can Swagger point to the gateway_url_without_port when deploying the microservices to PCF? (I have used jHipster cloudfoundry subgenerator to deploy the service to PCF so it ought to have handled this internally?)
2. Do I need to point the baseUrl to be the same as Gateway in *swagger-ui/index.html* or elsewhere in the subgenerator code?
3. Or, is this something that can be done in *manifest.yml* by specificying explicit routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed for the time being by specifying the hostname:

```
Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host(GATEWAY_ROUTE_WITHOUT_PORT) //Add
            .apiInfo(apiInfo)
            .forCodeGeneration(true)
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
            .select()
            .paths(regex(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN))
            .build();
```

Comment: Where do you do this change ?

Comment: @freemanpolys I made this change in the autogenerated SwaggerConfiguration.java file, which was created by jHipster.